# How does reward mechanism works on Proof-of-Authority consensus?

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, proof-of-stake

By following this [tutorial](http://blog.enuma.io/update/2017/08/29/proof-of-authority-ethereum-networks.html). I have created a private chain based on `Proof-of-Authority`. Please see my [CustomGenesis.json file](https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/a4af791650b44b71cce4cb1e61df7316).

I have started my chain:

```
> geth --datadir /Users/ethereum/POA/private --unlock 0xd531eab21f883abe0f79103188bfc6468712f409 --mine --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal console

INFO [01-16|15:53:58] Unlocked account                         address=0xD531EAb21f883aBe0F79103188bfc6468712f409
INFO [01-16|15:53:58] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [01-16|15:53:58] Starting mining operation
INFO [01-16|15:53:58] Commit new mining work                   number=22 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=116.62µs
INFO [01-16|15:53:58] Successfully sealed new block
```

*I observe that:* Balance of my each account remains unchanged if there is no transaction on the block. If there is a transaction, authorities' balances, slightly increase (I couldn't figure out with what percent each account gain a reward).

Also at each mined block,miner address returns: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

```
web3.eth.getBlock(179).miner
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

**[Q]** How does reward mechanism works on `Proof-of-Authority` consensus? Is there any `gas price`? Who gains the used `GAS` via transaction with what percent as a reward on the each block?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Do you mean Proof of Authority, not Proof of Stake? (That tutorial is for PoA.)

Comment: Isn’t Proof of Stake and Proof of Authority same? Is there any difference between them? @Richard Horrocks

Comment: Hi @Alper. There's a difference. PoA uses centralised, authority nodes to mint/approve new blocks being added to the chain. PoS, depending on how it's implemented, is more decentralised, and allows anyone to participate in the validation of blocks via a voting mechanism.

Comment: Doesn't on POA authorized users, which allow to seal votes, will allow new users to be authorized also under clique()? @Richard Horrocks